# How to define a contructor for <...auto...>

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

With the following program, which is an extract from something larger that I'm experimenting with, I get an error message that seems to be related to the constructor for `fixed_string`

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

template<std::size_t N>
struct fixed_string {
    static const constexpr std::size_t size__ = N;

    constexpr fixed_string(char const* s) :
            buf("") {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= N; ++i)
            buf[i] = s[i];
    }
    constexpr operator char const*() const {
        return buf;
    }
    constexpr bool operator==(const char* other) const {
        return ::strncmp(buf, other, N) == 0;
    }
    template<std::size_t M>
    constexpr bool compare(const fixed_string<M>& other) const {
        return (N == M && ::strncmp(buf, other.buf, N) == 0) ? std::true_type(): std::false_type();
    }

    char buf[N + 1];
};

template<std::size_t N>
fixed_string(char const (&)[N]) -> fixed_string<N - 1>;

////////////////////////////////////////////

template<fixed_string TARGET_NAME, fixed_string THIS_NAME>
concept NameMatches = (TARGET_NAME.compare(THIS_NAME));

template<fixed_string NAME, typename TYPE>
class Member {
public:
    static const constexpr fixed_string name__ { NAME };

public:
    template<fixed_string TARGET_NAME>
    const TYPE& get() const requires NameMatches<TARGET_NAME, TYPE::name__> const {
        return member_;
    }

protected:
    TYPE member_;
};

template<typename ... MEMBERS>
class Container: public MEMBERS... {
};
```

The error messages are:

```
../src/test-concepts.cpp:43:35: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   43 |  const TYPE& get() const requires NameMatches<TARGET_NAME, TYPE::name__> const {
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:43:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘fixed_string(fixed_string<...auto...>)’
../src/test-concepts.cpp:8:12: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int N> fixed_string(const char*)-> fixed_string<N>’
    8 |  constexpr fixed_string(char const* s) :
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:8:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src/test-concepts.cpp:43:35: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘N’
   43 |  const TYPE& get() const requires NameMatches<TARGET_NAME, TYPE::name__> const {
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:5:8: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int N> fixed_string(fixed_string<N>)-> fixed_string<N>’
    5 | struct fixed_string {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:5:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src/test-concepts.cpp:43:35: note:   mismatched types ‘fixed_string<N>’ and ‘fixed_string<...auto...>’
   43 |  const TYPE& get() const requires NameMatches<TARGET_NAME, TYPE::name__> const {
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:28:1: note: candidate: ‘template<long unsigned int N> fixed_string(const char (&)[N])-> fixed_string<(N - 1)>’
   28 | fixed_string(char const (&)[N]) -> fixed_string<N - 1>;
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:28:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../src/test-concepts.cpp:43:35: note:   mismatched types ‘const char [N]’ and ‘fixed_string<...auto...>’
   43 |  const TYPE& get() const requires NameMatches<TARGET_NAME, TYPE::name__> const {
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/test-concepts.cpp:43: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

This is part of a project using templates that overloads a given function (`get` in this case), for which there is only one suitable candidate that fulfils the constraint. The value that the constraint operates on is a name - a string literal - not a const string variable, which is passed as a non-type parameter to an instantiation of the template: something like:

```
Container<Member<"fred", std::string>, Member<"bert", int>, Member<"alfie", bool>> some_values;
```

I want to be able to retrieve a value using something like

```
int result = some_values.get<"bert">();
```

I have had difficulty finding much information about the "`<...auto...>`" specialisation of the template. I presume this is an internal representation used by `gcc` for constant, non-type values.

The error messages point me to the lack of a suitable overloaded constructor for `fixed_string`. What should this be?

Comment: Unrelated: `operator==(const char*)` and `compare` doesn't seem to be in agreement. Why does `N == M` need to be `true` in `compare`? One may now `static_cast<const char*>(the_rhs_fixed_string)` and use `operator==(const char*)`  and get `true` where `compare` would return `false`.

Comment: Compare was intended for a single specific purpose: to ensure two strings were absolutely identical within the context of the constraint. But your comment is well taken - I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that `fixed_string` is a **template** class, not a class.

So, when you define a concept as

```
template<fixed_string TARGET_NAME, fixed_string THIS_NAME>
concept NameMatches = (TARGET_NAME.compare(THIS_NAME));
```

you have that `fixed_string TARGET_NAME` (`fixed_string THIS_NAME` also) doesn't works because `fixed_string` isn't a type. I mean: `fixed_string<5>` is a type, not `fixed_string`.

I know that you have a deduction guide that, given the literal string, deduce the template parameter for the `fixed_string`, but remain the problem that the concept should works with elements of different types (`fixed_string` of different lengths).

I suppose you can solve the problem with `auto`

```
template <auto TARGET_NAME, auto THIS_NAME>
concept NameMatches = (TARGET_NAME.compare(THIS_NAME));
```

but, when you declare `Member`, you have the same problem: `fixed_string NAME` doesn't works because `fixed_sting` (without a length) isn't a type.

```
template<fixed_string NAME, typename TYPE>
class Member
```

Unfortunately, if you use `auto`

```
template <auto NAME, typename TYPE>
class Member
```

defining a `Member` with a literal string argument (`Member<"bert", int>`, by example), nothing bring `"bert"` to a `fixed_string`.

Suggestion: what about a `fixed_string` without a template argument?

Comment: That's a lovely, helpful answer. Oddly, GCC seems quite happy without specifying the parameter N for fixed_string. I wonder if I've found a hole in the compiler, because CLANG complains long and hard about every instance when I use a simple char* to initialise a fixed_string.


Your idea for a fixed_string without template argument may have legs. I'll try after I've cooked dinner.

Comment: @Nicole - Have you declared a `Member` object in g++? Maybe the compiler doesn't make the check without a `Member` declaration.

Comment: You **can** use CTAD for a (non-type) template parameter.  That’s good: it would be hard to implement `fixed_string` without its template parameter and with no dynamic allocation.

Comment: @Max66 You're quite correct. I'm not sure how that was missed from the example. A quirk of my editing, I suppose. I'm sorry it's missing, but it was really only for background. It seems to me the major issue is how to define a fixed_string class.

Comment: @Davis That's a nice idea. I added a user-defined template deduction guide, without any change in the error messages. I added  template<std::size_t N> fixed_string(const fixed_string<N>&) -> fixed_string<N>; after the existing CTAD guide.

Comment: @Max66 - where you say "defining a Member with a literal string argument (Member<"bert", int>, by example), nothing bring "bert" to a fixed_string" seems to be an example of where the GCC compiler works correctly, by applying CTAD it is able to infer the template argument for fixed_string.  I wonder if this was an oversight by the GCC developers when implementing concepts. I'll ask on the GCC mailing list.